# How to add <canvas> support to my tests in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, jsdom, jestjs

In my [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) unit test I am rendering a component with a [ColorPicker](http://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#usage-display). The `ColorPicker` component creates a canvas object and 2d context but returns `'undefined'` which throws an error `"Cannot set property 'fillStyle' of undefined"`

```
if (typeof document == 'undefined') return null; // Dont Render On Server
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); 
canvas.width = canvas.height = size * 2;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // returns 'undefined'
ctx.fillStyle = c1; // "Cannot set property 'fillStyle' of undefined"
```

I'm having troubles figuring out why I can't get a 2d context. Maybe there an issue with my test config?

```
"jest": {
  "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-tools"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "jsx",
    "js",
    "json",
    "es6"
  ],
  "testFileExtensions": [
    "jsx"
  ],
  "collectCoverage": true
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's because your test doesn't run in a real browser. Jest uses `jsdom` for mocking the necessary parts of the DOM to be able to run the tests in Node, thus avoiding style calculation and rendering that a browser would normally do. This is cool because this makes tests fast.

On the other hand, if you need browser APIs in your components, it's more difficult than in the browser. Luckily, [`jsdom` has support for canvas](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#canvas-support). You just have to configure it:

> jsdom includes support for using the [canvas](https://npmjs.org/package/canvas) package to extend any `<canvas>` elements with the canvas API. To make this work, you need to include canvas as a dependency in your project, as a peer of jsdom. If jsdom can find the canvas package, it will use it, but if it's not present, then `<canvas>` elements will behave like `<div>`s.

Alternatively, you could replace Jest with some browser-based test runner like [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/). Jest is [pretty buggy](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/230#issuecomment-149841819) anyway.

Comment: I'm switching over to karma. Installing the canvas package dependencies would be too much trouble to document for others. Thanks!

Comment: Old question/answer, but Jest has improved a lot since then and to get canvas working with jsdom (on most systems) all you need to do is `npm install canvas-prebuilt` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-prebuilt

Comment: @ChidG thank you for that info. the normal canvas package is impossible to build on windows 10, at least for me...

Comment: i have installed canvas also,even after that jest is failing to detect this canvas element,I have to use jest only as per project requirement...can you please help me out,even i tried with canvas-prebuilt...same problem.please help

Comment: Using create-react-app with Jest/Enzyme, I can confirm that adding canvas-prebuilt per @ChidG fixed canvas context errors.

Comment: In case anyone comes looking for a resolution to this, Jest comes with a very old version of `jsdom`. If you add `jsdom` to your dependencies and add a resolution to `"jest/**/jsdom": "13.0.0"`, this should fix it.

Comment: @kb_ this returns `error Received malformed response from registry for undefined. The registry may be down.`

Comment: Within a project from an up to date version of CRA, I just had to run `npm i -D canvas` as suggested almost 7 years ago, and the tests with Jest and react-testing-library started working for the canvas (which in our case is included in the react-signature-canvas package)

Answer (score 50):

For those looking for examples using create-react-app

Install

```
yarn add --dev jest-canvas-mock
```

Create a new `${rootDir}/src/setupTests.js` with

```
import 'jest-canvas-mock';
```

Comment: in my case, i added `jest-canvas-mock` to my `jest.config.js` like so `setupFiles: [
    "jest-canvas-mock"
  ]`

Comment: create react app does not have jest.config.js file do we need to create it? and how it should look like when we add setupFiles: [ "jest-canvas-mock" ]?

Comment: What imports this mysterious new `setupTests.js` file? **How** is it *magically* used?

Comment: downvote reason: the next answer down explains context, whereas this just says "add a library" and in fact doesn't work in my context (CRA, src/, no eject, single canvas in component, React Testing Library). "Add a library" is a poor solution generally, even if it works, and to do so without understanding the problem, which this answer doesn't address, is risky for several reasons.

Answer (score 28):

Jest / jsdom can handle canvas elements if the library [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) is installed.

Thus uninstall `jest-canvas-mock` (if installed) and install `canvas`:

```
npm uninstall jest-canvas-mock
npm i --save-dev canvas
```

Comment: it works for me with create-react-app.

Comment: This is the best answer for create-react-app/react-scripts 4+

Comment: Took quite a while to find a clean solution - jest-canvas-mock did not work for me but this answer did.  create-react-app with react-scripts 4.0.3

Comment: I intially tried with jest-canvas-mock, but this is really helpfull.

Comment: Do we need to add canvas to jest config in package.json to run it?

Answer (score 6):

For my use case I did simple monkey patching like this

```
beforeEach(() => {
    const createElement = document.createElement.bind(document);
    document.createElement = (tagName) => {
        if (tagName === 'canvas') {
            return {
                getContext: () => ({}),
                measureText: () => ({})
            };
        }
        return createElement(tagName);
    };
});
```

No need to install canvas-prebuilt or sinon.

Comment: TypeError: ctx.measureText is not a function

Comment: oh found my own comment months later

Comment: @Jacob past you had the same issue

Comment: @Jacob How did you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue. I'm deploying to gitlab ci to run my tests, and since npm canvas requires an installation of Cairo, using that wasn't a viable option.

All I really wanted to do was mock the implementation through Jest so that it doesn't actually try to create a real context.  Here's how I solved it:

*added to package.json*

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": ["./tests/setup.js"],
}
```

*tests/setup.js*

```
import sinon from 'sinon';

const createElement = global.document.createElement;
const FAKECanvasElement = {
  getContext: jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      fillStyle: null,
      fillRect: jest.fn(),
      drawImage: jest.fn(),
      getImageData: jest.fn(),
    };
  }),
};

/**
 * Using Sinon to stub the createElement function call with the original method
 * unless we match the 'canvas' argument.  If that's the case, return the Fake 
 * Canvas object.
 */
sinon.stub(global.document, 'createElement')
  .callsFake(createElement)
  .withArgs('canvas')
  .returns(FAKECanvasElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

[jest-canvas-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-canvas-mock) will work nice.

1. Install with `npm i --save-dev jest-canvas-mock`
2. In your jest **jest.config.js** add `"setupFiles": ["jest-canvas-mock"]` attribute.
   *(If you already have a setupFiles attribute you can also append jest-canvas-mock to the array eg  `"setupFiles": ["something-xyz.js", "jest-canvas-mock"]`).*

All Done.

Answer (score 2):

Even though 90% of the answers concentrate on mocking the canvas functionality, I will extend the answer by [Colin D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2129219/colin-d) giving an example on how to do visual regression testing of canvas in jest. Also, note that I do not use `jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen` or `jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen` as `jsdom` itself can handle it.

I am using:

```
chart.js v4.4.0
react-chartjs-2 v5.2.0
jsdom v19.0.0
jsdom-screenshot v4.0.0
jest v27.4.3
jest-image-snapshot v5.2.0
@jest/globals v27.4.2
@testing-library/jest-dom v5.16.0
@testing-library/react v12.1.2
```

and in my `jest.config.js` I have:

```
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
setupFilesAfterEnv: [
  '<rootDir>/jest.setup.afterEnv.js',
],
```

and in my `jest.setup.afterEnv.js` I have:

```
import { expect } from '@jest/globals';

import { configureToMatchImageSnapshot } from 'jest-image-snapshot';

const toMatchImageSnapshot = configureToMatchImageSnapshot({
  failureThresholdType: 'pixel',
  customSnapshotsDir: `${__dirname}/test/snapshots/`,
});

// extend Jest expect
expect.extend({ toMatchImageSnapshot });
```

With the setup above I can get an image out of the jest test of a generic `<Canvas />` component.

```
const getCanvasSnapshot = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, failureThreshold = 0) => {
  const image = canvas.toDataURL();
  const data = image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
  const snapshot = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');

  expect(snapshot).toMatchImageSnapshot({ failureThreshold });
};

describe('<Canvas />', () => {
  test('render into canvas', () => {
    // @see https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258
    const Canvas = (props: any) => {
      const { draw, ...rest } = props;
      const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);

      React.useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current as unknown as HTMLCanvasElement;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        draw(context);
      }, [draw]);

      return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...rest} />;
    };

    const App = () => {
      const draw = (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#0000ff';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(50, 50, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
      };

      return <Canvas draw={draw} width={100} height={100} />;
    };

    const { container } = render(<App />);

    const canvas = container.querySelector('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    getCanvasSnapshot(canvas);
  });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To test canvas output in jest you need to do the following:

Make sure you are using at least jsdom 13. You can do this by including the jsom package for jest, for 14 it is:

`jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen`

And configuring jest to use this

`jest --env=jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen`

or in the `package.json`

```
"jest": {
   ...
   "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
```

Include the `canvas` npm package. (as of 2.x this includes built version so canvas-prebuilt is deprecated).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create an image snapshot test from a canvas in jest with react-testing-library and jest-image-snapshot. That's sort of buzzwordy but it worked nicely.

If you are able to properly setup your jest testing with node-canvas (not jest-canvas-mock or similar) then you can literally call toDataURL on the canvas element.

```
  import {render, waitForElement} from 'react-testing-library'
  import React from 'react'
  import { toMatchImageSnapshot } from 'jest-image-snapshot'

  expect.extend({ toMatchImageSnapshot })

  test('open a canvas', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <YourCanvasContainer />,
    )
    const canvas = await waitForElement(() =>
      getByTestId('your_canvas'),
    )
    const img = canvas.toDataURL()
    const data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '')
    const buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64')
    expect(buf).toMatchImageSnapshot({
      failureThreshold: 0.001,
      failureThresholdType: 'percent',
    })
  })
```

I found that I needed to use a low threshold rather than directly comparing the image/png data URL because there were two pixels that were just randomly different when running on travis-CI

Also consider manually upgrading jest environment jsdom to  jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen or jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen (other answers on this page suggest similar) and refer to https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1782

Answer (score 1):

If you are using create-react-app, install jest-canvas-mock using `npm i --save-dev jest-canvas-mock` and at the top of your test files put `import 'jest-canvas-mock'`

Answer (score 1):

If you can`t install the library as stated in the common answer above.

Try mock canvas in that way

```
window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function () {
    return {
        fillRect() {},
        clearRect() {},
        getImageData(x, y, w, h) {
            return {
                data: new Array(w * h * 4)
            };
        },
        putImageData() {},
        createImageData() { return [] },
        setTransform() {},
        drawImage() {},
        save() {},
        fillText() {},
        restore() {},
        beginPath() {},
        moveTo() {},
        lineTo() {},
        closePath() {},
        stroke() {},
        translate() {},
        scale() {},
        rotate() {},
        arc() {},
        fill() {},
        measureText() {
            return { width: 0 };
        },
        transform() {},
        rect() {},
        clip() {}
    };
}

window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL = function () {
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using react, in my case.

```
npm uninstall jest-canvas-mock

npm i --save-dev canvas
```

These two commands are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the canvas package, because jest converts the canvas to div so after installing this package your test cases will work as same as canvas need to work.

```
npm install canvas
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install -D canvas-prebuilt@1
```

This provides support for canvas for jest.This even works if someone is getting error due to Lottie.js.

Comment: Seems like as of `Jun 23, 2020`, the installations **fails**