# react-scripts test raises TypeError unrelated to the component being tested

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-scripts

I'm testing a component that uses [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/), but the test suite fails on import of the license of it, and it's unrelated to the component being tested.

```
import React from 'react';
import RelatorioVendas from './RelatorioVendas';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('renders the "RelatorioVendas" component.', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <RelatorioVendas/>
    );
    wrapper.simulate("gridReady");
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

The error:

```
src/routes/Dashboard/RelatorioVendas.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'measureText' of null

      35 | import ValidationService from '../../services/ValidationService';
      36 |
    > 37 | import { LicenseManager } from "ag-grid-enterprise";
         | ^
      38 | LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("***********");
      39 |
      40 | class RelatorioVendas extends Component {

      at node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/canvas/hdpiCanvas.js:258:45
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/canvas/hdpiCanvas.js:264:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/scene/scene.js:4:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/chart/chart.js:4:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/chart/cartesianChart.js:17:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/chart.js:31:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/chartingService.js:15:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/menu/menuItemMapper.js:16:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/menu/enterpriseMenu.js:29:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/main.js:5:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/Dashboard/RelatorioVendas.js:37:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/Dashboard/RelatorioVendas.test.js:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        8.645s
```

How am I supposed to test my project if jest is going to raise random errors from internal libraries being imported? Is there a way to skip import-related errors?

Comment: Enzyme via Jest is trying to render your component and it is doing stacking building blocks in which your third party component came in the way that it need to stack. You more likely have setup issue of jest not being able to find the needed component. Lookup Jest resolver which finds node_modules

Comment: I have the same problem, you were able to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this issue as well.  For me, it turned out to be an issue with Jest not supporting canvas, unless you opt in.  The answer listed here: [add canvas support for jest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55141040/1454806) fixed my issue. Hope this helps!

My test failure:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read property 'measureText' of null

> 1 | import Table from 'core-ui/components/Table';
    | ^
  2 | import spinner from '@vestmark/core-ui/source/assets/loading-spinner.gif';
  3 | import React, { Component } from 'react';
  4 | import Util from '@/js/ip-util';

at node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/canvas/hdpiCanvas.js:309:41
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/canvas/hdpiCanvas.js:314:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/scene/scene.js:8:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/chart/chart.js:8:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/chart/cartesianChart.js:32:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/chart.js:54:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/charts/chartingService.js:24:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/menu/menuItemMapper.js:26:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/menu/enterpriseMenu.js:50:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/main.js:10:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@vestmark/core-ui/source/components/Table/Table.js:1:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/main/webapp/content/js/components/Transactions/TransactionsTable/TransactionsTable.js:1:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/test/javascript/spec/content/js/components/TransactionsTable.spec.js:6:1)
```

My table component is built using the Ag-Grid-enterprise.